# How to use wide characters in ncurses TextBox?

Tags: python, ncurses, textpad

I need to use `get_wch()` to get unicode characters with curses in python.

```
 ch = stdscr.get_wch()
```

I want to use [TextBox](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#textbox-objects) to get chars. However, it seems it returns just ascii characters. How can I print unicode chars with TextBox?

Comment: The [curses documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#) says "**Note**

Since version 5.4, the ncurses library decides how to interpret non-ASCII data using the `nl_langinfo` function. That means that you have to call `locale.setlocale()` in the application and encode Unicode strings using one of the system’s available encodings."

Comment: It's more complicated than that, because the interface uses *bytes objects* rather than *strings*, requiring some juggling by the script to convert the encoding.